# How do I avoid displaying a matplotlib too large greather than 2^16 pixels?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pixel, figure

I'm trying to display a large amont of signals in a matplotlib figure. I have a value in my interface to set the spacing that exists between signals. My issue is, if that value is too large, I get this error:

ValueError: Image size of 1266x121000 pixels is too large. It must be less than 2^16 in each direction.

and the soft crashs. What I would like to do is avoiding the soft to crash. Does it exist a way to detect if that error will occur and then tell to the user that the value is too large?  I could also adjust the dpi for large figure but the error could still comes anyway.

here a minimal example:

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import sys
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas

class Mon_Graph(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Mon_Graph, self).__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.mainHBOX = QHBoxLayout()
        self.spacing_e = QLineEdit('1')
        self.mainHBOX.addWidget(self.spacing_e)
        self.graph= graphic(self)
        self.mainHBOX.addWidget(self.graph)
        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.mainHBOX)

        self.Sigs = np.random.rand(100,100)*10
        self.spacing_e.editingFinished.connect(self.update_sigs)

    def update_sigs(self):
        self.graph.update()

class graphic(QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(graphic, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.scene = QGraphicsScene(self)
        self.setScene(self.scene)
        self.figure = plt.figure(facecolor='white')
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)

        self.widget = QWidget()
        self.widget.setLayout(QVBoxLayout())
        self.scroll = QScrollArea(self.widget)
        self.scroll.setWidget(self.canvas)


        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.axes.set_xlabel("Time (s)")

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.scroll)
        self.setLayout(layout)


    def update(self):
        Sigs = self.parent.Sigs 
        self.figure.clear()
        plt.figure(self.figure.number)
        plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, bottom=0.01, right=1, top=1, wspace=0.0 , hspace=0.0 )
        self.axes = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1)
        spacing = float(self.parent.spacing_e.text())

        for i in range(Sigs.shape[0]):
            plt.plot(Sigs[i,:]+i*spacing)

        self.axes.autoscale(enable=True, axis='both', tight=True)

        self.canvas.setGeometry(0, 0, self.parent.width()-100, (self.parent.height()-100)*spacing)
        self.canvas.draw_idle()

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Windows')
    ex = Mon_Graph(app)
    ex.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If I put 20 in the lineedit then it is ok but if I put 200, it crashes with the previous error.

Answer (score -1):

Just add a condition in your update method to check if any of both dimensions of `Sigs` surpass 2^16 (before the call to `plot`)

Comment: Ok, but how do I know that the image will be over 2^16?

Comment: The `shape` attribute gives you the size of its dimensions. So verify that `Sigs.shape(0)` and `Sigs.shape(1)` aren't above 2^16

Comment: I don't see the point. In my example, the max value is 10. What's is the link with the size of the generated image to display which is in pixel?